# Filling only when one curve is below the other

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to fill the area between two curves only when curve-1 (Black) is *below* curve-2(Blue).  So In this example, I don't want the middle portion shaded but just the left and right tails to be shaded. It is not possible for me to always solve for the points of intersection since it might involve using `FindRoot` and stuff and may not be worth the trouble. Can someone please tell me how to do that. Thanks.

```
Plot[{0.8333*H + 16.928*H^0.25 - 85, 
  Max[-9 + Max[H - 80, 0], H - 80]}, {H, 0, 700}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick], Black}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14696/5

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Plot[{0.8333*H + 16.928*H^0.25 - 85,  Max[-9 + Max[H - 80, 0], H - 80]}, {H, 0, 700}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick], Black}, 
     Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Yellow, Transparent}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice! You beat me by a second.

Comment: @belisarius sweet thanks!