# Special case of filling between curves

Tags: plotting, filling

I have two curves plotted on the same plot. To the left of a given domain value, I want to fill between curve 1 and the x-axis; to right of that value, I want to fill between the two curves.

[image]

Comment: What are people supposed to do with your figure?

Comment: @Nina: Did you see these posts https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33126/filling-between-curves, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20721/filling-only-when-one-curve-is-below-the-other?

Comment: Thank you for the link, but that could be applied only there is an intersection in between.

Comment: @Nina To help you, people will need the data or the analytical expressions that generated those curves. We can't help you otherwise.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an adaptation of m_goldberg's answer that uses a single plot for his example:

```
Plot[
    {
    c2[x],
    ConditionalExpression[c1[x], x<.7],
    ConditionalExpression[c1[x], x>.7]
    },
    {x, 0,1},
    PlotStyle->{Red, Blue, Blue},
    Filling->{2->{Axis, LightBlue}, 1->{{3}, LightBlue}}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way to do what you are asking for.

Functions and given point

```
c2[x_] := x^(1/2)
c1[x_] := x^3
x0 = .7;
```

Now we make three plots ...

```
p1 = Plot[{c1[x], c2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> {Blue, Dashed, Line[{{x0, 0}, {x0, 1}}]}]
```

[image: p1]

```
p2 = Plot[c1[x], {x, 0, x0}, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image: p2]

```
p3 = Plot[{c1[x], c2[x]}, {x, x0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: p3]

... and combine them with `Show`.

```
Show[p1, p2, p3]
```

[image: all]