# Filling and Shading an Harmonic Curve

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting, filling

Suppose I have an equation plotted as shown:

```
Plot[(HarmonicNumber[K] - HarmonicNumber[K - r]) (HarmonicNumber[K] - 
 HarmonicNumber[-1 + r]) /. K -> 10, {r, 0, 11}, Filling -> 0.4]
```

[image]

But what I really want is to have the two (triangular?) filling FLIPPED inside at $x \approx2$ and $x \approx9$. The direction of filling of the upper (semi-circular) part is not important. Preferably it can be Top/outside.

Can anybody help with this flipping?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [(9684)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9684/121), [(14696)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14696/121), [(18964)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18964/121), [(25169)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25169/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way, copying once more from @J.M.'s answer here: [How can I fill under a function in a plot just to right of a specified vertical line?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18964/how-can-i-fill-under-a-function-in-a-plot-just-to-right-of-a-specified-vertical/19202#19202)

Using @b.gatessucks definition of `f`:

```
f[r_, k_] = (HarmonicNumber[k] - HarmonicNumber[k - r]) (HarmonicNumber[k] - 
      HarmonicNumber[-1 + r])
```

we can do:

```
With[{ff = f[r, 10]}, 
   Plot[{ConditionalExpression[ff, ff < 0.4], 
         ConditionalExpression[ff, ff >= 0.4]}, {r, 0, 11}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> Axis, 2 -> Top}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, 1], 
   FillingStyle -> LightRed]]
```

based on the ideas linked above (using `ConditionalExpression`), getting the same result as in @b.gatessucks' answer.

The advantage of this approach is that you can easily modify the fillings (and other options) for the individual parts (but if you use a complicated function, I suspect it could turn slow (due to the added conditions)

Answer (score 5):

One way :

```
f[r_, k_] = (HarmonicNumber[k] - HarmonicNumber[k - r]) (HarmonicNumber[k] - 
 HarmonicNumber[-1 + r])

sol1 = r /. FindRoot[f[r, 10] == 0.4, {r, 2}];
sol2 = r /. FindRoot[f[r, 10] == 0.4, {r, 9}];
m = FindMaximum[f[r, 10], {r, sol1, sol2}][[1]];

Show[Plot[f[r, 10], {r, 0, 11}], 
     Plot[f[r, 10], {r, 0, sol1}, Filling -> Bottom], 
     Plot[f[r, 10], {r, sol1, sol2}, Filling -> {1 -> m}], 
     Plot[f[r, 10], {r, sol2, 11}, Filling -> Bottom]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could draw an invisible second function (a block) and have the filling occur between the two:

```
f[r_, k_] = (HarmonicNumber[k]-HarmonicNumber[k-r])(HarmonicNumber[k]-HarmonicNumber[-1 + r]);

max = NMaxValue[{f[r, 10], 0 < r < 11}, r]
min = NMinValue[{f[r, 10], 0 <= r <= 11}, r]

Plot[
  {
    f[r, 10], 
    Rescale[ Boole[f[r, 10] > 0.4], {0, 1}, {min, max}]
  }, 
  {r, 0, 11}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks all. You been quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For version 7:

*Warning: for simplicity `r` is not localized in either method; Formal Symbols advised in practice.*

```
hf[K_] := With[{H = HarmonicNumber}, (H[K] - H[K - r]) (H[K] - H[r - 1])]

Plot[
 {If[hf[10] < 0.4, hf[10]], If[hf[10] >= 0.4, hf[10]]},
 {r, 0, 11}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Bottom},
 PlotStyle -> Black
]
```

[image]

Or:

```
Plot[
 {If[hf[10] < 0.4, hf[10]], If[hf[10] >= 0.4, hf[10]]},
 {r, 0, 11}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Bottom, 2 -> Top},
 FillingStyle -> LightGray,
 PlotStyle -> Black
]
```

[image]