# Filling only part of a plot

Tags: plotting, filling

I have something plotted on [-6,6] but I would like to fill only the part from [-5,5] (to the axis). I'm looking through the documentation but I'm not terribly well-versed in Mathematica and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a function to use to show how to do it? You can start by looking at `Filling`

Comment: Related: [(9684)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9684/121), [(14696)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14696/121), [(18964)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18964/121), [(25169)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25169/121), [(25640)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25640/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[{r1_, r2_}, opts___] := Plot[Sin[x], {x, r1, r2}, opts]
Show[f[{-6, 6}], f[{-5, 5}, Filling -> Axis]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great, thank you so much! I was resorting to doing a second, completely separate plot of the function on a smaller domain and Showing both of those, seemed so inelegant.